# Obj-C controller.view.frame get REAL size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in a wAny/hAny UI and I set all spaces of it to its superview resulting in the standard size of 600x600.

Because this is an application with multiple pages I need to do some math for swiping to the next page (horizontal) and there is that one block of code that I am using which causes white spaces in between the pages:

```
CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageNumber;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
```

The problem here is that `frame.size.width` always returns 600 instead of the actual size of the view, causing the mentioned gaps in between the views. If I hardcode frame.origin.x as `pageNumber*414` (iPhone 6 Plus screen width) everything works perfectly but that's certainly not the best way of doing it.

I could also just obtain the screen width as the UIScrollView fills it completely and therefore would result in the same value but I feel like that's not considered good code. And although this would definitely be enough for my app I'd really like to learn how this is properly done in Objective-C. Also, regarding the upcoming split screen mode on iOS 9 this would result in unexpected behavior.

So what else can I use to get the actual size of the frame?

Comment: In what method are you trying to get the size of the view? The system doesn't set the size until the layout pass, which happens after `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Oh man that makes sense. I did it in my viewWillAppear, of course it can't really "know" the value at this point. So would you recommend me to put it in the viewDidAppear? EDIT: OK just did, got a minor lag after starting the app now, will see what I can do about that but I am going to figure that out for sure. Put as answer and I will tick

Comment: If you want to do it in your view controller, do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find out the view size in `viewWillAppear:`, because the system doesn't lay out the views until after that method returns. The earliest you can get the correct view size in your view controller is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now run the code above 2 times, at first I get my first viewController through that algorithm in the viewWillAppear, then I apply it to all views afterwards in the viewDidAppear.